# Learning Rust and Documentation

Tags: rust

I'm working on an [Exercism](http://exercism.io) exercise and I'm confronted with this:

```
fn test_no_allergies_means_not_allergic() {
    let allergies = Allergies::new(0);
    assert_eq!(false, allergies.is_allergic_to(&Allergen::Peanuts));
    assert_eq!(false, allergies.is_allergic_to(&Allergen::Cats));
    assert_eq!(false, allergies.is_allergic_to(&Allergen::Strawberries));
}
```

When I look at `Allergen::Peanuts`, I think that this is a symbol like Ruby, but I can't find anything in the documentation about it other than the idea of crates and modules. I can't seem to think that `Allergen` is a module with separate crates mainly because the `README` leads me to this:

> The list of items (and their value) that were tested are:
>
> - eggs (1)
> - peanuts (2)
> - shellfish (4)
> - strawberries (8)
> - tomatoes (16)
> - chocolate (32)
> - pollen (64)
> - cats (128)
>
> So if Tom is allergic to peanuts and chocolate, he gets a score of 34.

It has to be some kind of enum with each of those values and some kind of bitmask but I just can't find any documentation to show me more about the symbols. I'm not willing to give up and I want to learn as much as possible about Rust but the docs seem lacking.

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding enums, objects, symbols, and where can I get more documentation regarding Rust?

Answer (score 1):

Rust doesn't have a bitflags type in the language or standard library. But there is a [bitflags](https://doc.rust-lang.org/bitflags/bitflags/macro.bitflags!.html#example) crate, which you could write

```
#[macro_use] extern crate bitflags;

bitflags! {
    flags Allergies: u32 {
        const ALLERGEN_EGGS = 1,
        const ALLERGEN_PEANUTS = 2,
        ...
        const ALLERGEN_CATS = 128,
    }
}

impl Allergies {
    pub fn is_allergic_to(&self, other: &Allergies) -> bool {
        self.intersects(*other)
    }
}

let allergies = Allergies::empty();
assert!(!allergies.is_allergic_to(&ALLERGEN_CATS));
// ^ unfortunately we don't support associated constants 
//   so we have to name it ALLERGEN_CATS instead of Allergies::CATS.
assert_eq!((ALLERGEN_PEANUTS | ALLERGEN_CHOCOLATE).bits(), 34);
```

Don't forget to add `bitflags` to the `[dependency]` section in your Cargo.toml.

---

If you don't want to depend on an external crate, you could base your type on integer types together with the bitwise operations. [They are the same as C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) *except* that we use `!` instead of `~` for bitwise-not.

The constants have to be defined in a [separate module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html#defining-modules):

```
#[allow(non_upper_case_globals)] // <- silence 8 warnings
mod Allergen {
    pub const Eggs: u32 = 1;  // <- use a new type if you like
    pub const Peanuts: u32 = 2;
    ...
    pub const Cats: u32 = 128;
}
```

or as a C-style enum (associate enum members with [explicit discriminants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#enumerations)):

```
enum Allergen {
    Eggs = 1,
    Peanuts = 2,
    ...
    Cats = 128,
}

let score = (Allergen::Peanuts as isize) | (Allergen::Chocolate as isize);
```

Both of which don't convey the concept that the values form bitflags. Seriously, you should avoid these bitflags-workarounds if you could use external crates.

Comment: I know how to use the bitmask and it has bit shifting which allows one to compare one of the constants values. I thought about the list of constants but thought that there was something a little better. And also, you constants don't match the test at all. I can't change the tests so Allergen::Peanuts is how it needs to state not snake case unfortunately. But thanks.

Comment: @macshaggy: As I said, Rust doesn't support bit flags natively. (You could try [C-style enum](http://rustbyexample.com/custom_types/enum/c_like.html) but they don't work like bit-flags.)

Comment: @macshaggy If you use the `bitflags` crates the constants should be named LIKE_THIS because they are defined as module constants and that's the standard naming convention. You could call it `Cats` make a `mod Allegens { pub use {Cats, ...} }` but that is ugly :).

Comment: I understand what you are saying but the tests are what they are and I can't change them. Again, this is an exercise given to me and I have to code towards the test and external crates are not to be used.

Comment: @macshaggy The tests don't reflect how Rust is commonly written then *Sigh*. See update.

Comment: can enums have methods? UPDATE: never mind I think I know how to implement the methods. And once I get it working I'll post it here to show you how you can bit shift values using the input as the bitmask.